# Starcluster python3 support by 2to3 okay?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, starcluster

Is it okay to use 2to3.py to make Starcluster work under the environment of python3?

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to *try* but `2to3` isn't a fix-all that will magically make it work, there's somethings it can't fix automatically.

In general the approach you should take if you are trying to port this yourself is, after understanding the code, run `2to3` and then manually change cases it doesn't catch. If this doesn't work wait for the developers to reply to the [comment you left on the github issue for this](https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/514).